# rails4 dependent destroy callback error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, callback

I have a `role` attribute on the `ProductUser` model. Users can be deleted by the `owner` (role), and I wanna make sure the owner can't delete himself while the `product` exists. However, when the `product` gets deleted all the `product_users` should be gone including the owner.

The following code throws an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed - Failed to destroy the record` error  when I try to delete the `product`. I guess this is because of the order of the execution due to the `dependent: :destroy`. How can I make this work?

```
class ProductUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product, touch: true

  before_destroy :check_for_owner

  def check_for_owner
    if product && role == "owner" #If I use simply: if role == "owner", it still doesn't work.
      errors[:base] << "Owner can't be deleted!"
      return false
    end
  end
end


class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_users, dependent: :destroy
  ....
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered simply not showing the delete button for the `ProductUser` record if the user is the owner?

In any case, if you use a foreign key rather than dependent destroy then the destroying will happen at the database level and the product user models won't be instantiated which would solve your issue.

So in a migration

```
def change
  add_foreign_key :product_users, :products, on_delete: :cascade
end
```

Then on product remove the dependent destroy option

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_users
end
```

With the on delete cascade option the database will destroy the product's product users when the product is deleted.

Comment: j-dexx, I'm not showing it, but wanna make sure everything works fine. I'm also using foreign key constraint, but without the cascade at the moment. Btw. Is this the best solution? I mean can't I do something only in rails or both in db (cascade) and rails? I usually like to do double protection like let's say there is an attribute that must be present then I do `validate :attribute, presence: true` on the rails side and `null: false` on the db side.

Comment: No, you can't really that I can think of.